# How to make some PSD file not to save as overwrite

Tags: adobe-photoshop, designers, mockup

Is there anything safety lock like feature for psd file to preserved its original file? I  have free mock ups psd file from graphic design community site, I always use them, but some time I accidentally save the psd file (overwrite the mock up psd), resulting mess mock up and I will need to download the mock up again from the site.

Comment: You could change the file to `read only` in mac finder or windows explorer.  It will prevent any changes to the file.

Answer (score 3):

[image: File >> Save As...]

1: Whenever you download a file you can immediately make a copy and rename it according to your project.

2: Or after opening the PSD do a File > > Save As... then name it appropriately.

Comment: Be aware that while self-promotion is absolutely fine within your profile, it is highly discouraged in answers unless it *directly* relates to the actual answer. Randomly throwing in your web site link is frowned upon and doing it repeatedly may be seen as advertising.